# Get Specific Child Element Using elementFromPoint()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `SVG` map that contains multiple `PATH` objects. There's an overlaying image over that map, so whenever I want to call some event on the map, I have to use `elementFromPoint`. My function was structured somewhat like this:

```
function CallEvent(e){

$('.overlay-image').hide(0);

var mapObj = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);   

$(mapObj).click();

$('.overlay-image').show(0);
}
```

When I was using `SHAPE` for the map, it was working perfect, but now I use SVG map, it does not work because the `elementFromPoint` selects the entire `SVG` element and I need to grab the `PATH` object that is located at the coordinates the user made a click at.

Is it possible to find that `PATH` object using this function? All `PATH` objects have id and class.

Finally the SVG map is structured like this: `<SVG><D><PATH></PATH></D></SVG>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery Nearest Element plugin](http://gilmoreorless.github.com/jquery-nearest/) could do what you need.

You could use something like `$.nearest({x: 100, y: 100}, 'path')` to identify the nearest path.